# Tensorflow seq2seq tutorial 404

Tags: tensorflow

i'm currently trying to use the seq2seq library but i can't access to the tutorial it is pointing 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/index.html

Has it been replaced by something else or function are deprecated ?

wants to try different seq2seq and understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, for the late answer, but you can always try to find broken or unmaintained older websites or links at [`archive.org`](https://archive.org/) with their wayback machine.

I've found [your link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170129002833/https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/seq2seq/) there, too.

Comment: thanks even if was late, i learnd it from keras blog but still good to read :)